# cargar imagen con electron como recurso de la aplicación

Tags: electron

Estoy creando una aplicación con electrón que tendrá 3 ventanas:

1. Un `Loader` (se encarga de verificar si existen actualizaciones o no).
2. <s>Configuración y Actualizaciones.</s>
3. <s>La Ventana principal donde se carga una URL.</s>

Problema:
Estoy tratando de integrar una imagen al `Loader`.

entiendo que debería tener un archivo `loader.hml` en donde colocaría el `html` para que muestre la imagen.

```
const appIcon = new Tray('/app/resource/images/icon.png')
const win = new BrowserWindow({ icon: '/app/resource/images/icon.png' })
```

pero es posible cargar una imagen de un tamaño especifico sin tener que cargar el archivo html. como si se tratase de un icono o recurso de la aplicación?

la idea seria agregar esta imagen como parte de la aplicación o instalación principal y mostrarla mientras el loader hace las verificaciones de actualizaciones.

****Update:** Código que tengo:

Main.js**

```
const electron = require('electron');
const url = require('url');
const path = require('path');
const isAdmin = require('is-admin');

const { app, BrowserWindow, Tray } = electron;
const Menu = electron.Menu;
const MenuItem = electron.MenuItem;

let loaderWindow;

function appLoader() {
  loaderWindow = new BrowserWindow({ width: 400, height: 200, frame: false });
  loaderWindow.loadURL(`file://${__dirname}/app/loader.html`);
}

app.on("ready", appLoader);
```

**Código html (loader.html):**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="UTF-8">
</head>
<body style="display: block; margin: 0px; overflow: hidden;">
<img src="assets/img/loader.png" alt="Browser Loader" style="width: 100%; margin: 0px 0px;padding: 0px 0px; overflow: hidden;">
</body>
</html>
```

Otra alternativa existe:

```
new BrowserWindow({
  backgroundColor: "#F7C136"
});
```

o:

```
mainWindow.setBackgroundColor('#56cc5b10')
```

**Pero no encuentro algo para recursos como una imagen.**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

ya he resuelto la cuestión:

```
function appLoader() {
  loaderWindow = new BrowserWindow({ width: 400, height: 200, frame: false });
  //loaderWindow.loadURL(`file://${__dirname}/app/loader.html`);
  loaderWindow.loadURL(
    url.format({
      pathname: path.join(__dirname, "/app/assets/img/loader.png"),
      protocol: "file",
      slashes: true,
    })
  );
}
```

`loadURL` puede cargar tambien archivos... pero hoy 22/04/2021 tiene una nota de que url.format esta en estatus de `deprecated`, asi que no se que otra solución darle en un futuro de momento funciona correctamente.